# Calculate time range in org-mode table

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-table

Given a table that has a column of time ranges e.g.:

```
|  <2015-10-02>--<2015-10-24> |
|  <2015-10-05>--<2015-10-20> |
....
```

how can I create a column showing the results of org-evalute-time-range?

If I attempt something like:
    #+TBLFM: $2='(org-evaluate-time-range $1)

the 2nd column is populated with

```
 Time difference inserted
```

in every row.

It would also be nice to generate the same result from two different columns with, say, `start date` and `end date` instead of creating one column of time ranges out of those two.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have your date range split into 2 columns, a simple subtraction works and returns number of days:

```
| <2015-10-05>       | <2015-10-20> |        15 |
| <2013-10-02 08:30> | <2015-10-24> | 751.64583 |
#+TBLFM: $3=$2-$1
```

Using `org-evaluate-time-range` is also possible, and you get a nice formatted output:

```
| <2015-10-02>--<2015-10-24>           | 22 days                    |
| <2015-10-05>--<2015-10-20>           | 15 days                    |
| <2015-10-22 Thu 21:08>--<2015-08-01> | 82 days 21 hours 8 minutes |
#+TBLFM: $2='(org-evaluate-time-range)
```

Note that the only optional argument that `org-evaluate-time-range` accepts is a flag to indicate insertion of the result in the current buffer, which you don't want.

Now, how does this function (without arguments) get the correct time range when evaluated is a complete mystery to me; pure magic(!)

Comment: That is magic. Thanks! I don't know why I didn't try just subtracting. Good to know that works as well. Nice answer.

Comment: The "magic" in this case appears to be that `org-evaluate-time-range` will find any timestamp range in the same line, and during formula evaluation point is in the cell whose formula is being calculated.