# how to use TBLFM combined to results from org-evaluate-time-range

Tags: emacs, org-mode

From a previous post ([Calculate time range in org-mode table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291580/calculate-time-range-in-org-mode-table/33292887#33292887)), I was able to use the org-evaluate-time-range function in a table.

I'd like to sum the obtained durations. However, searching for how to do that, I noticed the following behavior of TBLFM mode.

```
| <2015-12-09 01:29>--<2015-12-09 08:43> | 7 hours 14 minutes | 98 hours minutes |
| <2015-12-09 08:29>--<2015-12-09 08:43> | 14 minutes         | 14 minutes       |
#+TBLFM: $2='(org-evaluate-time-range)::$3=$2
```

Here in the third column, it seems that it is the product that is calculated. Any reason for that?

What I would like to is to sum the duration with a macro like that

```
#+TBLFM: $2='(org-evaluate-time-range)::@3$2=vsum(@1$2..@2$2)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The right-hand side of formulas like `$3=$2` is evaluated by [`calc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html), and `calc` knows nothing about the `7 hour 14 minutes` syntax.  In fact, `calc` can do symbolic calculations, and it reads `7 hour 14 minutes` as the product `7*hour*14*minutes` where `hour` and `minutes` are variables.

The time syntax that `calc` understands is `HH:MM[:SS]`.  This is illustrated by the [org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Durations-and-time-values.html#Durations-and-time-values).

`TBLFM:` has a flag `;T` to format numeric values as time this way, but that does not work for timestamp ranges.  So if you really want to start from a timestamp range, maybe one way is to write your own function to convert ranges to seconds:

```
Evaluate this first:
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (defun convert-time-range-to-seconds (range)
    (if (string-match org-tr-regexp-both range)
        (let ((start (match-string 1 range))
              (end (match-string 2 range)))
          (round (- (org-time-string-to-seconds end)
                    (org-time-string-to-seconds start))))
      ""))
#+END_SRC

| time stamp range                               | as seconds |   as time |
|------------------------------------------------+------------+-----------|
| <2015-12-09 Wed 01:29>--<2015-12-10 Thu 08:42> |     112380 |  31:13:00 |
| <2015-12-28 Mon>--<2015-12-31 Thu>             |     259200 |  72:00:00 |
| <2015-12-11 Fri>--<2015-12-13 Sun>             |     172800 |  48:00:00 |
|------------------------------------------------+------------+-----------|
|                                                |            | 151:13:00 |
#+TBLFM: $2='(convert-time-range-to-seconds $1)::$3=$2;T::@>$3=vsum(@2..@-1);T
```